# Вывод полей ACF wp

Tags: wordpress

Создал произвольные поля в ACF pro, но так вышло что нужно использовать данный блок на нескольких страницах - и значения тянуть везде одинаковые.

поля повторяющиеся вывожу через `<?php while (have_rows('powers')): the_row(); ?>`

пока сделал только для главной, но как вытянуть эти значения для других страниц не могу понять. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У ACF есть [оффсайт](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/) и прекрасная документация, а по вашей проблеме

```
<?php $field = get_fields($post_id); ?>
```

и даже в другом посте можно задать ID нужного вам

Comment: да я читал , проблема в том что я делаю это на кастомных страницах, которые не относятся к записям и т.п , я пробывал получить данные с помощью данной функции . Не вышло

Comment: Вам нужно получить поля из определенного поста. Тогда вводите вручную ID вместо $post_id, и должен получить. Возможно глупо звучит, но плагин активирован? И на кастомных страницах Вордпресс-функции работают?

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую снова